# Flux scope in a React application

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have been working on React components for a while and yesterday just did my first Flux example from https://github.com/tildedave/flux-feature-flags

Just wondering the scope of Flux. In Flux we have Stores, Dispatchers etc, are they available just for one React component, each React component has it's own Flux structure?

Or they are available globally? so the whole application shares Stores, Dispatchers etc, making them available to all React components used in this app

Answer (score 0):

@stanleyli flux essentially a design pattern which tells us about how to have a one direction flow of data so that we can achieve interesting things like easy debugging, timeline, logging etc.
if you are interested in implementing flux on your own I would recommend to look into [phrontend](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/phrontend) or [redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: yes I understand Flux is architecture, Redux or other similar frameworks are implementations. The one I am using seems to be Facebook's own implementation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/flux